# SQL join tables and filter based on comparisons

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a query where if I change my on condition to a where later in the query I get different results, and would just like an explanation as to why the result is different and how to get one versus the other.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT
            tHeader.SOPNUMBE AS [Invoice Number],
            tHeader.ACTLSHIP AS [Invoice Date],
            tHeader.CUSTNMBR,
            tHeader.CUSTNAME,
            tHeader.SLPRSNID

            FROM METRO.dbo.SOP30200 tHeader
            WHERE
                MONTH(ACTLSHIP) = 6
                AND YEAR(ACTLSHIP) = 2016
                AND SOPNUMBE like 'I%') header
    JOIN
        (SELECT *
            FROM METRO.dbo.SOP30300
            WHERE CSLSINDX = 137
        ) lineItems
        on
            lineItems.SOPNUMBE = header.[Invoice Number]
            /* ISSUE COMPARISON 1 --- Returns 1265 rows ---
            AND lineItems.ITEMNMBR NOT LIKE '%ENVISION%'
            AND lineItems.ITEMNMBR NOT LIKE '%REBATE%'
            AND lineItems.ITEMNMBR NOT LIKE '%EPSON%'*/   
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT 
            cogs.ITEMNMBR,
            cogs.ITMSHNAM
            FROM METRO.dbo.IV00101 cogs
            WHERE
                cogs.IVCOGSIX = 137
        ) gpItems
        on gpItems.ITEMNMBR = lineItems.ITEMNMBR
        /* ISSUE COMPARISON 2 --- Returns 1255 rows ---*/
        WHERE
            gpItems.ITMSHNAM <> 'TM'
            AND gpItems.ITMSHNAM <> 'Rebate'
ORDER BY SOPNUMBE
```

So a quick explanation of this - any rows that I get from `lineItems` table they have an `ITEMNMBR` column. Associated to that column from the `gpItems` table is `ITMSHNAM`, and not every `ITEMNMBR` from the `lineItems` table is in the `gpItems` table. The `ITEMNMBR` column is a little too ambiguous, and subject to change. So I would like to filter my results based on `ITMSHNAM` not being equal to `TM` or `Rebate`, yet I still want to return any rows that don't have an `ITMSHNAM`.

The comparisons are equivalent, because any of the `lineItems.ITEMNMBR` comparisons will always have those `gpItems.ITMSHNAM` comparisons, but like I said, those `ITEMNMBR`s are subject to change.

If I use `ISSUE COMPARISON 1` and comment out the second comparison it gets me the results I want with a row count of `1265`, however, because of the reasoning above, I want to use the `gpItems` comparison to filter the results. But when I use `ISSUE COMPARISON 2` my row count goes down to `1255`. I looked to see what items are excluded, and it seems it is excluding any values that don't have an `TIMSHNAM`.

How can I fix my `gpItems` comparison to return the required `1265` rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding one more condition to your constraints to allow returning rows where `gpItems.ITMSHNAM` is null.

Change:

```
WHERE
  gpItems.ITMSHNAM <> 'TM'
  AND gpItems.ITMSHNAM <> 'Rebate'
```

To this:

```
WHERE
  gpItems.ITMSHNAM NOT IN ('TM', 'Rebate')
  OR gpItems.ITMSHNAM IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just for completeness sake - is there another method of accomplishing the same result?